# Google Line Chart: can I insert error bars?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization, linechart

Cheers all.

I'm using a line chart, created with the Google API for draw charts ([this chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)).

It's working well, but now I have a problem. I have to insert some **error bars** or something similar (for example, the *variance*). Is it possible to it with the google API? How can I do it?

My target is to have something like [this](http://www.think-cell.com/en/support/documentation/images/slideview/errorbars.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible,
the line chart supports column roles, the one you're looking for is [interval](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles)

Comment: can I do the same thing if I use the method 
"data.setValue( i, 0, new Date(dates[i]) ); "?

I can't find anything for this way!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775644/role-on-dynamic-google-chart-interval where I ask for this with more details.