# Role on dynamic google chart (interval)

Tags: dynamic, intervals, google-visualization, role

How can I use this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles if I populate the graph dynamically?

This is part of my code:

```
...
data.addRows(dates.length);
for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
    if (i!=0){
        data.setValue( i, 0, new Date(dates[i]) ); 
        temp = graph[dates[i]];
        var j = 0;
        if (temp){
            for (j = 0; j < groups.length; j++){
                if ( groups[j] in temp){
                    var volume = parseFloat(temp[groups[j]]);
                    console.log(i + '  ' + j + '  ' + volume);
                    data.setValue( i, j+1, volume )
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        data.setValue( i, 0, new Date(dates[i]) ); 
        var j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < groups.length; j++){
            data.setValue( 0, j+1, 0 )
        }
    }
}
...
```

After I set the value with 'data.setValue', how can I set also the role? (I need for the interval value) Something like 'data.setRole' would be wonderful!! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the `DataTable` without any roles, and then create a `DataView` that assigns roles to the columns in the view. The documentation shows how to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#dataview.setcolumnsmethod):

> **`DataView.setColumns` Method**
>
> When creating a view, you can explicitly set the role of a column.
>   This is useful when creating a new calculated column. See
>   `DataView.setColumns()` for more information.

The `DataView.setColumns()` [help file](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns) explains how to do this as follows:

> `setColumns(columnIndexes)`
>
> 1. columnIndexes - An array of numbers and/or objects (can be mixed):
>              Numbers specify the index of the source data column to include in the view. The data is brought through unmodified. If you
>      need to explicitly define a role or additional column properties,
>      specify an object with a sourceColumn property.
> 2. Objects specify a calculated column. A calculated column creates a
>      value on the fly for each row and adds it to the view. The object
>      must have the following properties:
>
>    - calc [function] - A function that will be called for each row in the    column to calculate a value for that cell. The function
>        signature is    func(dataTable, row), where dataTable is the source
>        DataTable, and    row is the index of the source data row. The
>        function should return a    single value of the type specified by
>        type.
>    - type [string] - The JavaScript type of the value that the calc    function returns.
>    - label [Optional, string] - An optional label to assign to this    generated column. If not specified, the view column will have no
>        label.
>    - id [Optional, string] - An optional ID to assign to this generated    column.
>    - sourceColumn - [Optional, number] The source column to use as a    value; if specified, do not specify the calc or the type property.
>        This is similar to passing in a number instead of an object, but
>        enables you to specify a role and properties for the new column.
>    - properties [Optional, object] - An object containing any arbitrary    properties to assign to this column. If not specified, the view
>        column will have no properties.
>    - **role [Optional, string] - A role to assign to this column. If not    specified, the existing role will not be imported.**

So if your interval column is column #3, for instance, you would say:

`dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'interval'}]);`

The above sets columns 0, and 1 as-is, without a role, while column 2 is assigned as an interval column.

**EDIT**

Responding to the comments, the intervals are in the data set. Here is an example:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Interval A', 'Interval B'],
    ['2003',  100,   95,       125],
    ['2004',  110,   96,       150],
    ['2005',  120,   97,       175],
    ['2006',  130,   98,       200],
    ['2007',  140,   99,       225],
    ['2008',  150,   100,      250]
  ]);

  // Create Data View using columns 2 & 3 as intervals
  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'interval'}, {sourceColumn: 3, role: 'interval'}]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(dataView,
         {width:600, height:400,
          hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
        );
}
```

You include the interval values in the original data table as columns. You then use a dataview to change those columns to 'interval' role columns. Then you draw the dataview. This will provide error bars (interval columns) as expected.

Comment: yes, I've already read this, but... 1) here: "dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {sourceColumn: 2, role: 'interval'}]);" where have I to put the value of the interval? 2) I use the 'setColumns' only for role and I keep the 'setValue' for the values?

Comment: I've tried this: 
"dataView.setColumns([{sourceColumn: j+1, role: 'interval'}]);
data.setValue( i, j+1, volume, volume+100);"

but it doesn't work... where do I make mistake? :)

Comment: First you set the `DataTable` with the columns in the order you want (including your interval columns), but with no roles defined. After you create the `DataTable`, then you create a new `DataView` that uses the exact same columns, but sets the 'role' column for the one that contains the interval.

Comment: well... and where is the value of the interval?

Can you make me an example?